# question on definition of separability of field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, definition

[image]
[image]

It’s quoted from Rotman’s advanced modern algebra. How can an element be transcendental in an algebraic extension? Should separability of field extension be defined on any field extension and there typos in the quoted definition?

Answer (score 2):

based on the definition in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension, I think I can just ignore the transcendantal part now.

[image]

Comment: That’s right. That slip should have never been allowed in a published text.